# Protect myself from losing access to bucket when setting iam permissions with terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm using terraform manage access to a google cloud bucket:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "default" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.admin"
    members = var.isProd ? [
      ...
    ] : [
      ...
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_policy" "policy" {
  bucket = var.bucket
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.default.policy_data
}
```

What's a bit scary after running this though - I lost access to the bucket on my personal account, even though I created it. This was somewhat expected from my read of the documentation, but now it begs the question, how can I protect myself from completely losing access to a bucket if my service account is deleted?

Is there a way for me to set things up so an account inherits default access to a google cloud resource, so that I'm protected from something catastrophic, like losing access to my production terraform state somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You should (!) be able to grant yourself storageAdmin on the project and then not be able to un-permit yourself by applying permissions to the project's buckets.

**Please** test this on a sacrificial project and bucket to prove that this works.

Same-same for org|folder for their projects.

IAM inheritance is aggregative on Google Cloud; permissions are OR'd not AND'ed so you can give but not take away (once given to a parent).

Please also consider using add binding to policy commands if these exist in the Terraform provider for GCP.

If you really do want to overwrite the resource's policy, you can continue to use set but, more often, you want to add or remove bindings to a policy.